# How to delete a partition using a foreach statement in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, virtual-machine

I need to delete a partition from a particular hard drive on a virtual computer. I can do this manually, one computer at a time, with no problem. However, I need to be able to run a PowerShell script that will read a text file containing a list of computers and have the script iterate through each computer and remove that particular partition.

I know what the disk number and partition number is for each machine so there isn't a need for an "if" statement. I also know that the machines have this particular partition to be removed.

The script I am trying to use is below. When I run it in debugger all of the script is read except for the "Get-Partition" line. The script iterates through the computer list but doesn't pick up the partitions and therefore doesn't select the one I need to have deleted.

I have researched Google for various keywords relevant to getting the information I need but I can't find anything that addresses this problem specifically. Any suggestions or assistance with this is greatly appreciated.

I connect to the server that hosts the machines via a PowerCLI code command. The code is below:

```
$computers = Get-Content -Path C:\Temp\computers.txt

foreach ($computer in $computers)
{
   Get-Disk
   Get-Partition
   Remove-Partition -DiskNumber 0 -PartitionNumber 3
}
```

Comment: You're just running three disk/partition cmdlets in a row. These are each going to run independently and will not pass info along to each other. If you're trying to pass info along from one to the next you should use the pipeline or store the values from each cmdlet. What errors do you get when you try running this (possibly using -WhatIf in order to test without actually deleting partitions)?

Comment: @music2myear thank you. The output I get is below:

Remove-Partition : No matching MSFT_Partition objects found by CIM query for instances of the ROOT/Microsoft/Windows/Storage/MSFT_Partition class on the  CIM server: SELECT * 
FROM MSFT_Partition  WHERE ((DiskNumber = 0)) AND ((PartitionNumber = 3)). Verify query parameters and retry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the commands inside the `foreach` block with only this :

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer { Remove-Partition -DiskNumber 0 -PartitionNumber 3 }
```

I suggest to test this command on one test computer that can be
destroyed before executing on all the computers in the list.
You must be very sure about the disk and partition numbers
in all these computers.